# Como faço para dar um click em uma imagem e executar uma função

Tags: python, qt, widget, pyqt

A linguagem é python e o gráfico é qt4.
Tenho uma qlabel e um widget escondido. Preciso que quando a qlabel for clicada o widget apareça, e quando for clicada novamente ele desapareça.
Pesquisei bastante, mas só encontro informações de que não é possível evento click na qlabel, e recomendação de usar o button. O problema é que não posso usar o button ele não tem como por uma imagem, pois ele não tem a função setPixmap, igual a qlabel tem. Alguém sabe alguma forma de fazer o evento click numa qlabel, ou como fazer um button ter uma foto nele igual a qlabel faz?

Comment: Eu não vou responder porque não uso Qt no Python. Mas tem como sim. Se optar por usar o QLabel mesmo, você pode criar uma classe sua herdando de QLabel e reimplementar o método [`mousePressEvent`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlabel.html#mousePressEvent) pra fazer algo no pressionamento do botão do mouse. Ou, se preferir usar QPushbutton pra exibir imagem (porque também dá), basta adicionar a imagem como um ícone (usando [`setIcon`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractbutton.html#icon-prop)) ou usar `image` no estilo (com algo como `setStyleSheet("image: url(imagem.jpg)")`, por exemplo).

Comment: Outras alternativas (embora os códigos sejam em C++, devem servir como base pra vc) aqui: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2671842/setting-background-image-for-qpushbutton

Comment: usando esse stylesheet nao faz nada, não dá erro, nem carrega nada..
Pesquisando na internet encontrei um método através do icon, porém a imagem fica muito pequena, quero que a imagem ocupe o espaço inteiro do botão, que tem o tamanho de 100x100

Comment: icon_data = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
icon_pixmap = QPixmap()
icon_pixmap.loadFromData(icon_data)
icon = QIcon(icon_pixmap)
self.btnBotao.setIcon(icon)

Comment: Consegui resolver, era so aumentar o tamanho do icon nas propriedades do button xD

Comment: Que bom que você conseguiu resolver. Nesse caso, que tal você mesmo oferecer uma resposta explicando em detalhes (adicione os trechos de código relevante, por exemplo) como resolveu e marcá-la como aceita? Assim você potencialmente ajuda outras pessoas no futuro. Se fizer, ganha o meu +1.

Comment: O Código eu postei na mensagem anterior. O tamanho do icone eu alterei no qtdesign mesmo, só fui em icon e defini os tamanhos da largura e da altura é coisa básica

Comment: Mensagem anterior? Não existe "mensagem" anterior. E eu entendi o que você fez. Estou só sugerindo que você mesmo crie uma resposta para demonstrar como fez isso. Lembre-se: este site não é um fórum. Se não fez ainda, por favor faça o [tour].

Comment: icon_data = urllib.urlopen(url).read() icon_pixmap = QPixmap() icon_pixmap.loadFromData(icon_data) icon = QIcon(icon_pixmap) self.btnBotao.setIcon(icon) – Mega Anim 5/06 às 6:45 << essa foi a mensagem com o codigo que resolveu

Comment: Sim, eu entendi. Mas isso não é exatamente uma "mensagem", e sim um comentário. Ele se perde facilmente em meio a tantos outros comentários, e dificulta pra alguém que possa precisar no futuro (por ter a mesma dúvida/problema que você). Por isso, o *ideal* é você mesmo **responder** a sua pergunta, colocando esse código **bem formatado** no corpo da resposta.

Comment: Tem um campo "Sua resposta" mais abaixo. Coloque o seu código lá, que eu te ajudo a formatar. Eu poderia responder no seu lugar, mas ai você perde a oportunidade de ganhar reputação por isso. :) Leia esse texto, por favor: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: Então, mas eu não consigo responder minha própria pergunta, o site não deixa, uma vez eu respondi minha pergunta, e me advertiram pra não fazer isso, e disseram que eu devia incluir coisas apenas na pergunta original.

Comment: Olha, até onde eu sei não há limite de reputação para responder à própria pergunta. Vc tem certeza que está tentando fazer isso no lugar correto (há um campo para isso mais pra baixo nesta página, como eu já disse antes)? Além disso, ou você se confundiu com o que te disseram (não seria pra não responder *no corpo* da pergunta?) ou quem te disse isso não sabia o que falava.

Comment: O unico campo que tem aqui é o botão azul: "Responder à sua pergunta" da vez que tentei veio a mensagem que não podia responder

Answer (score 1):

O código a seguir acho que se aproxima do que é pedido:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *

class ExtendedQLabel(QLabel):

    def __init(self, parent):
        QLabel.__init__(self, parent)

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, ev):
        self.emit(SIGNAL('clicked()'))

class Window(QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent = None):

        QWidget.__init__(self, parent)

        self.label1 = ExtendedQLabel(self.tr(u"Clique aqui"))
        self.label2 = ExtendedQLabel(self.tr(u"Olá!"))
        self.label2.setVisible(False)

        self.connect(self.label1, SIGNAL('clicked()'), self.toggleLabel2)

        layout = QHBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.label1)
        layout.addWidget(self.label2)

    def toggleLabel2(self):

        self.label2.setVisible(not self.label2.isVisible())

if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

A classe `ExtendedQLabel` herda a classe `QLabel`, incluindo o evento `clicked()`, que na verdade emite um sinal quando o evento `mouseReleaseEvent()` é chamado. O evento `clicked()` do `label1` é então conectado a uma função que alterna a visibilidade do `label2`.

Vi essa abordagem aqui: [An example on how to make QLabel clickable](http://popdevelop.com/2010/05/an-example-on-how-to-make-qlabel-clickable/). Parece que existe uma maneira nova e mais adequada de usar [sinais e slots](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/new_style_signals_slots.html), não usei porque isso é novidade para mim.